# JavaScript Array undefined element

Tags: javascript, arrays, undefined

I´ve got a function which should add an element at the start of an array.
But I always get an undefined element at the end of my array. I hope someone can help me :)

```
function putToFirst(e){
   var array = [];
   array.push(e);
   this.arrayList = array.concat(this.arrayList);
}
```

EDIT:

```
class List {

  constructor () {
    super()
    this.arrayList = [];
  }

  putToFirst(e) {
      this.ArrayList.unshift(e);
 }
}
```

thats the class. I create a new object from the class list and call the function putToFirst on this object. But I always get an Array with 'undefinded' in the end

Comment: Is `[].unshift()` broken in your browser?!

Comment: What's `e`? What's `this`? Try providing a [mcve].

Comment: Note that if you're going with `unshift` on `this.arrayList`, you'll mutate the array instead of replacing it with a new one.

Comment: e is an integer which should be added in to the array. this is the object on which the function is called

Comment: @Alex9677 — And what is that object? How are you testing the results? Provide a [mcve]

Comment: So, is it `this.ArrayList` or `this.arrayList`? They’re not the same thing.

Comment: Why do you invoke the mother constructor **super()** ?  Does your Class inherit from a mother Class

Comment: What plateforme do you execute your code in ?

Comment: You declared the property arrayList of your class in the constructor but after you call this.ArrayList. That can't work

Answer (score -4):

```
this.arraylist is wrong this represent a current object you are not currently using any class in above code you just need to change 

  function putToFirst(e){
   var array = [];
   var arrayList=[];
   array.push(e);
  arrayList = array.concat(arrayList);
  console.log(arrayList);
}
```

Comment: I wouldn’t assume that `this.arrayList` is wrong. However, your function creates a new and empty `arrayList` every time. This has nothing to do with appending new elements to the beginning of the array.

Comment: thanks for showing my mistak